# Tenserflow Keras model not accepting my python generator output

Tags: keras

I am following some tutorials on setting up my first conv NN for some image classifications.

The tutorials load all images into memory and pass them into model.fit(). I can't do that because my data set is too large.

I wrote this generator to "drip feed" preprocessed images to model.fit, but I am getting an error and because I am a newbie I am having trouble diagnosing.

These are processed only as greyscale images also.

Here is the generator that I made...

```
# need to preprocess image in batches because memory
# tdata expects list of tuples<(string) file_path, (int) class_num)>
def image_generator(tdata, batch_size):

    start_from = 0;

    while True:
                
        # Slice array into batch data
        batch = tdata[start_from:start_from+batch_size]
        
        # Keep track of position
        start_from += batch_size
        
        # Create batch lists
        batch_x = []
        batch_y = [] 

        # Read in each input, perform preprocessing and get labels
        for img_path, class_num in batch:
            
            # Read raw img data as np array
            # Returns as shape (600, 300, 1)
            img_arr = create_np_img_array(img_path)

            # Normalize img data (/255)
            img_arr = normalize_img_array(img_arr)
            
            # Add to the batch x data list
            batch_x.append(img_arr)
            
            # Add to the batch y classification list
            batch_y.append(class_num)
        
        yield (batch_x, batch_y)
```

Creating an instance of the generator:

```
img_gen = image_generator(training_data, 30)
```

Setting up my model like so:

```
# create the model
model = Sequential()

# input layer has the input_shape param which is the dimentions of the np array
model.add( Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape = (600, 300, 1)) ) 
model.add( MaxPooling2D( (2,2)) )

# second hidden layer
model.add( MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) )
model.add( Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu') )

# third hidden layer
model.add( MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add( Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu') )

# forth hidden layer
model.add( Flatten() )
model.add( Dense(64, activation='relu') )

# ouput layer
model.add( Dense(2) )

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# pass generator
model.fit(img_gen, epochs=5)
```

Then model.fit() fails from trying to call shape on an int.

```
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in _get_dynamic_shape(t)
    797 
    798     def _get_dynamic_shape(t):
--> 799       shape = t.shape
    800       # Unknown number of dimensions, `as_list` cannot be called.
    801       if shape.rank is None:

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Any suggestions on what I've done wrong??

Comment: What version of Keras are you using? Have you tried `model.fit_generator()`?

Comment: fit_generator is now obsolete.

Comment: Yes, `fit_generator` is now obsolete. Which is why I also asked for the Keras version.

Comment: I just installed the latest version from pip install tenserflow today. '2.3.1'

Comment: It is only "obsolete" in tf.keras, not in keras, note that these are two different libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Converting the outputs from the generator to numpy arrays seems to have stopped the error.

```
np_x = np.array(batch_x)
np_y = np.array(batch_y)
```

Seems like it didn't like the classifications as a std list of ints.

Comment: Yes, your generator should output numpy arrays